# How to get the current user

Tags: php, wordpress, include, echo

I'm trying to get the current user in WordPress as in the snippet below:

```
<?php
    include('/wp-admin/includes/user.php');
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); 
    echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login;
?>
```

but I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_get_current_user() in /membri/mysite/wordpress/getUser.php on line 3

What am I doing wrong and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Add  `include('/wp-admin/includes/pluggable.php');` (do not delete user one)

Comment: Where is your page located? Actually, you simply need `wp_get_current_user()` to return an array of the current user in WordPress.

Comment: I've solved the function calling, but now I've this problem:                                   Call to undefined function apply_filters() in /membri/mysite/wordpress/wp-includes/user.php on line 2525

Comment: my page is located in wp-admin

Comment: the error is in the user.php file

Comment: @GianLuke94 What error is in `user.php` file?

Comment: this: Call to undefined function apply_filters() in /membri/mysite/wordpress/wp-includes/user.php on line 2512

Comment: this is the code in the line 2512:                                                                       $user_id = apply_filters( 'determine_current_user', false );

Comment: @GianLuke94: `wp-admin` is not the right location! You shouldn't temper with files there. You should add your file either to your theme located in your `wp-content/themes/` directory or plugin directory, `wp-content/plugins/`. BTW: What exactly do you want to achieve? Can you elaborate a little?

Comment: Delete all the `include` from your file and put `require_once('wp-load.php');`

Answer (score 0):

Pls include the source file
wp_get_current_user() is located in

**wp-includes/pluggable.php**

For more details please refer

[Wordpress Documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user)

Comment: Why would you re-post somebodies comment as an answer without giving credit?

Comment: Sorry..  I'm not reposting your answer, i'm just refer this from wordpress documentation

Answer (score 0):

In your `functions.php`, you can do this:

```
function my_theme_get_user_id() {
    global $current_user;

    echo 'The current logged in user ID is: ' . $current_user->ID;
}
```

then, use an action hook or a filter to use it were needed.

In your theme, under the `wp-content/themes/` directory, you can simply do this directly in any of your files for view:

```
global $current_user;
echo 'The current logged in user ID is: ' . $current_user->ID;
```